# how to redirect url to jsp in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

(Should be an easy one-)

How can I redirect all urls of the pattern yada*.js into a my specific jsp. 
will this addition to my web.xml work:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MySpecific.jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>yada*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or perhaps I must use javax.servlet.filter for that purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd drop those files in a folder called `/yada` and then use an `url-pattern` of `/yada/*`.

If you don't want to do that, then hand-determining it in a filter is indeed the only resort.

---

**Update**: as per your update, you actually have a second question which wasn't directly obvious from your initial question: *"How to declare a JSP file as a servlet?"*. The answer is: use `<jsp-file>` instead of `<servlet-class>`.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>foo.jsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/foo.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>foo.jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Nevertheless, as stated in the comments, this is not the best practice. This smells to raw Java code in a JSP file which you should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to all extent.

Comment: but can servlet-name attribute direct to a jsp file and not a servlet?

Comment: Oh, I thought you already have a `<servlet><jsp-file>` for that. No, you can't do that alone. Use `<jsp-file>` instead of `<servlet-class>` in `<servlet>` and it'll work. It's however not the recommend way. JSP is the wrong tool for this. Raw Java code in JSP should be [avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) to all extent.

Comment: @helios: Ones asking this kind of questions often do :)

Comment: That' the solution I used eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the server the things that you can put in url-pattern are very limited.

Two are valid:

- an absolute path (no wildcards)
- *.ext

So that specification is not matching. I'd use a filter indeed.

PS: don't forget to specify <%page sourceEncoding=... contentType=... %> in the generating JSP :). And content-type should include charset=xxxxx

Comment: ok but how do I forward to JSP from a filter. I do I have to call the 'chain.doFilter()' after the forward command or before. and do I have to call it if the pattarn was found or only if the pattern was not found

Comment: I continue this thread in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415240/forward-request-from-a-filter
since I currently can't write more than a comment in this thread and the issue is not solved yet