# Forward request from a filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filter

I need to *forward my request* (to a jsp but I don't think it's matter) from an http.Filter
if the URI of the original request pass some validation that my filter runs.

I found this [page that faced similar task](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200111.mbox/%3C20011110161313.A24324-100000@localhost%3E)

Still I need to figure the following:

1. How can I get ServletContext in `doFilter()` method (in order to call forward API)  `getServletContext()` is not recignized
2. Do I have to `call chain.doFilter()` before the forward, after the forward or not at all?
   In addition do I have to call `chain.doFilter()`  if my validation passed or only if it fails (because in this case I won't continue to forward my page)?

This question actually continue [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414733/how-to-redirect-url-to-jsp-in-web-xml), 
to be more obvious, the code could be something like:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((HttpServletRequest)request);
            String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
            String contextPath = httpServletRequest.getContextPath();
            if (<this is my implementation of the validation of this filter>){                                      
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                "MySpecific.jsp").forward(request,response);

            }

        }
        chain.doFilter(request,response);

    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How can I get ServletContext in doFilter() method?

```
httpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext();
```

> Do I have to call chain.doFilter() before the forward, after the forward or not at all? In addition do I have to call chain.doFilter() if my validation passed or only if it fails (because in this case I won't continue to forward my page)?

I would say that if you forwarded the request, you should not call `chain.doFilter()` - the forwarded request will get filtered according to its own filter configuration. If your validation failed though, it depends on what the semantics of your web app are - if the original page is some sort of general error/login/welcome screen, you may want to continue to that when the validation failed. It is hard to say without knowing more of the context.

Answer (score 11):

To get the  `ServletContext`, you've got 2 options:

- Store off the `FilterConfig` during the initialization and call `FilterConfig.getServletContext()`
- call `HttpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext()`

I don't think you necessarily need the `ServletContext` to get the `RequestDispatcher` as you could just call `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()`.

In relation to `FilterChain.doFilter()` call, if you're forwarding, I would think you wouldn't make the call, as once you forward, I assume you don't want any of the standard behavior to take place. 
 If you don't forward (you don't fall into your if block), then I'd call the `FilterChain.doFilter()` method, however that assumes there is a target on the other end to be invoked.

Comment: both answers were fine. The other one was first.

Comment: Store off the FilterConfig during the initialization and call FilterConfig.getServletContext() This is my preferred method as do not have a session explicitly: