# How to map a filter for welcome-file in web.xml for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, mapping, servlet-filters

I have created a `Filter` to check the `Cookie`s with request object and `forward` the request accordingly thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3415240/803285) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9785254/803285) question..Now I want to map this `Filter` for just the `welcome-file` as I have declared it in `web.xml`.
Say I have `welcome-file` as `index.html` then I have to map the `Filter` for both `www.example.com/` and `www.example.com/index.html` but not for anything else such as `www.example.com/foo/*` or `www.example.com/*` is not allowed, I mean NOT anything except `welcome-file` request.
I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these to your web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.examples.myFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Well will this be helpful in `www.example.com` case? where it is not clear with URL pattern what file is going to be served by contanier?

Comment: yes, if you haven't changed the Host name in context.xml. '/' represent the root of the application and index.html will be served since you have mentioned the same in welcome-file and it should be in WebContent folder