# Tomcat displaying welcome-page before filter for jsp is executed

Tags: tomcat6, servlet-filters

I am using Tomcat 6.0.36 and the welcome-page is /Login.jsp
I have a filter in place so that it can display a different login page for mobile devices.
It works with URL mywebsite.com/Login.jsp, but the filter is bypassed when the URL is just mywebsite.com.

Is there a way to force it to execute?

I have found this page but it doesn't work in my case:

[How to map a filter for welcome-file in web.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158280/how-to-map-a-filter-for-welcome-file-in-web-xml-for-tomcat)

Thanks

My web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
...
<filter>
    <display-name>LoginPageFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>LoginPageFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.LoginPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginPageFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter - I had deleted it and put one quickly back together

```
public class LoginPageFilter implements Filter 
{
    public LoginPageFilter()  { }

    public void init ( FilterConfig fConfig ) throws ServletException { }

    public void doFilter ( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, 
    ServletException 
    {
        System.out.println ( "Filter being executed" );
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() { }
}
```

If the URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/gymfit/Login.jsp
```

then the message is printed to the console.

When the URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/gymfit/
```

the same page is displayed but the message is not printed out to the console

Comment: could you post your filter config in web.xml? also the code in the filter :)

Comment: I had deleted it for the time being, I quickly recreated a generic filter that has the same behaviour. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this line, this means only the request to '/Login.jsp' will the filter being executed

```
    <url-pattern>/Login.jsp</url-pattern>
```

if you want to apply this filter to all the path, change the config to:

```
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```