# Filter not executing for welcome page in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, gwt

I'm attempting to follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) to make my GWT/App Engine app crawlable.  I built a filter as described, and included the following in my web.xml:

```
  <filter>
     <filter-name>crawlFilterChain</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.project.name.server.service.CrawlFilterChain</filter-class>
  </filter>


  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>crawlFilterChain</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>BaconBits.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

I then attempted to test the configuration by loading this URL in a browser:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&_escaped_fragment_=page%3DEvent%26eventId%3D1138

The filter is invoked, but not for the initial "GET /" request when the page is first loaded (the one that returns the welcome file).  It's only invoked for subsequent RPC/AJAX requests, none of which have a query string.  Oddly, if I insert a non-existent resource after the / in the URL (such as index.html), the filter is invoked, and the appropriate HTML is returned.  What am I doing wrong? The behavior is the same in production.

This looks to be the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456762/tomcat-displaying-welcome-page-before-filter-for-jsp-is-executed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158280/how-to-map-a-filter-for-welcome-file-in-web-xml-for-tomcat), but using the same config as they recommend doesn't work.  Basically, the "GET /" request that returns the welcome file doesn't invoke the filter.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502012/web-xml-filter-wont-run-on-static-content/28503879#28503879) was the same problem, and the appengine-web.xml self-answer worked for me.