# .jsp pattern in web.config and getting the url

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

Regarding this post: [how to redirect url to jsp in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414733/how-to-redirect-url-to-jsp-in-web-xml)

it is obvious that one can make an url, for example, http://mypage.com/details/?id=20
where details is mapped to details.jsp

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>details</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/details.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>details</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/details/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, my question is as follows:

1. how would I get the "/details/" parameter from the url within a .jsp (or servlet)?
2. is it possible to format the url in this manner http://mypage.com/details/20/ and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get that and use it as variable using Spring MVC Framework
or **get the requestUri.**

example:   **mypage/detail/20**

```
String requestUri = request.getRequestUri();
int x = Integere.parseInt(requestUri.subString(requestUri.lastIndex('/',requestUri.length())));

out.println("value of x is " + x);
```

Try to study [Spring MVC Framework](http://youtu.be/Q6hZQ5SzGyM)