# URL changes after hit

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I try to hit the below URL

```
     https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com
```

it changes to onloading of the login page

```
    https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/
```

I just want to know how does the URL changes on hit. Can someone explain me this concept using Servlets

Comment: http 302 redirect......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to redirect the page :

1. You can specify the redirection rule in web.xml file. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414733/how-to-redirect-url-to-jsp-in-web-xml) for your reference.
2. You can redirect to specific page using [jstl](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_redirect_tag.htm) for <c:redirect > tag
3. You can redirect to some other page in servlet using `response.sendRedirect("pathOfThePage");`

Comment: I often see query strings get appended to the URL. How does this happen. I haven not seen any query strings appended to the URL but the URL changes to very long URL with query string appended to it. How does this happen. We use JSF

Comment: Its just way of passing some value to the servlet or controller using GET request. Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm) tutorial for form processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by URL redirect. For example, from a Servlet u can do the redirect using:

```
response.sendRedirect("location");
```

Here is the description of sendRedirect from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29):

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified
>   redirect location URL. This method can accept relative URLs; the
>   servlet container must convert the relative URL to an absolute URL
>   before sending the response to the client. If the location is relative
>   without a leading '/' the container interprets it as relative to the
>   current request URI. If the location is relative with a leading '/'
>   the container interprets it as relative to the servlet container root.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html. Simple yet powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of redirecting is `<jsp:forward page="forwardpage.jsp"></jsp:forward>`
from a jsp page you can redirect another jsp page using the above way
you can also use `response.sendRedirect("forwardpage");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `UrlRewriteFilter` as below:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/some/olddir/(.*)$</from>
   <to type="redirect">/very/newdir/$1</to>
</rule>

<rule match-type="wildcard">
   <from>/blog/archive/**</from>
   <to type="redirect">/roller/history/$1</to>
</rule>
```

you can read more about it [here](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html)

Comment: is UrlRewriteFilter a XML or a Java file?

Comment: its and XML file, `urlrewrite.xml` will be placed under the `WEB-INF` directory.